# What is word relating to wife of father in 1759 English (Somerset) baptism record?

Tags: 18th-century, baptism-records, somerset

This is from a 1759 baptism record in England. It reads, James, son of James Shepherd & Mary his **wife of ?????** baptized Jan 1 1759" The term is repeated for several other records but most are written something like "John Smith son of William Smith & his wife Elizabeth baptized Dec 15 1758." I have googled baptism terminology and haven't found anything close.
See [Image on Ancestry](https://www.ancestry.com/imageviewer/collections/60856/images/engl78030_d-p-pit-2-1-2_m_00036?ssrc=pt&treeid=153572901&personid=112120683056&hintid=&usePUB=true&usePUBJs=true&_ga=2.81509140.209361006.1640908387-1785324147.1604530472&pId=4681005):

[image: 1759 baptism record with unknown word]

Comment: I think it will be a place somewhere near Pitminster.

Answer (score 7):

It looks like `Corfe` to me which, as @PolyGeo suggested, is a [village near Pitminster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corfe).

Comment: Thank you both!